# Char equal the space

Tags: java, char, equals, space

This is my code.

```
public class main_class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        char e;
        int q=0;
        for(;;){
            System.out.print("Enter the symbol:");
            e=sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (e== ' '){
                q++;
            }
            if (e== '.')break;
        } 
        System.out.println("Spaces : " + q);
    }
}
```

The q is always 0, I have tried also:

```
if (e == ' ' || e == '\t' || e == '\r' || e == '\n' ) {
    // ...
}
```

and Character.isWhitespace(e). Thank you!

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Why the q is always 0? if I input the space

Comment: Your scanner is using whitespace as a delimiter.  The token you get from it is never going to start with a space.

Comment: White spaces are default delimiter.  So Scanner always stlips them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Space is not a input value of next().

try use

```
        String temp=sc.nextLine();
        e=temp.charAt(0);
```